# Transformar o catear entidad A en entidad B java hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Se puede hacer lo siguiente en java o hibernate.

Tengo la entidad (Persona) la cual tiene los siguientes atributos atributos (nombre completo, edad y fecha nacimiento, idEmpresa, idCliente ) esta proviene de la vista Persona, actualmente está vista es la única que se consume; se genera una vista materializada de Persona quedando con nombre PersonaVM su entidad contiene los mismos campos que Persona (nombre completo, edad y fecha nacimiento, idEmpresa, idCliente ).

Ahora se desea consultar en la vista PersonaVM lo cual necesito convertir el resultado a la entidad Persona.

He realizado las siguientes modificaciones.

```
Criteria cliente = this.createCriteria();

cliente.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(Persona.class));--no funciono

cliente.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Persona.class));--no funciono

List < Persona > lista = (List < Persona >) cliente.list(); --no funcionó
```

Alguna otra forma en la cual pueda hacer este transformación de una entidad a otra.

Saludos